# RDD[Vector] to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an instance of a `RowMatrix` that contains a single column. 
I am trying to turn this RowMatrix into a dataframe but I am not quite sure how to convert `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]` to a dataframe.

```
val mat: RowMatrix = new RowMatrix(centred)
val mat_rows = mat.rows // RDD[Vector]
```

I know that if I had two (or more) columns I could use the following piece of code

```
val mat_rdd = mat_rows.map(_.toArray).map{case Array(p0, p1) => (p0, p1)}
val df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(mat_rdd).toDF("f1", "f2")
```

The problem is that I have just a single column. If I modify the above code to create a single-column dataframe I get the following error:

```
overloaded method value createDataFrame with alternatives:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine in Spark 2.0.0:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix

val rows = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Array(Vectors.dense(1), Vectors.dense(1)))
val mat: RowMatrix = new RowMatrix(rows)
scala> mat.rows.map(_.toArray).map{ case Array(a) =>  a}.toDF("f1").show()
+---+
| f1|
+---+
|1.0|
|1.0|
+---+
```